# Linux command to look at other drives/partitions on computer from live CD

Tags: file-transfer, dd

So my friend’s computer crashed because the file system is corrupted. However, she needs files from the system, therefore, a reinstall wouldn’t do the trick as we still a way to recover the files.

My approach to solving this problem would be to boot a live version of Helix (an Ubuntu distro) from a USB, run the `dd` command to block copy the Windows partition to an external drive, and then using foremost to recover as much as we can.

In any case, I’m trying to find the command on the internet but to no avail. Does anyone know the command to view all partitions on the drive? Keep in mind that I’m trying to view it from a Live Helix CD.

Comment: Yes, I created a bootable USB from a live CD to run on the defective computer because I didn't want to take the hard disk out as it would void the warranty but I needed to access the disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer?** Linux—in and of itself—can be used to do what you are attempting to do. The most basic command to list block level devices and partitions is [`lsblk`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsblk) but you can also interpret the output of `cat /proc/partitions` if you don’t have `lsblk` installed. But perhaps you need to seek out an appropriate live CD for such purposes. This [Runtime Live CD](https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-live-cd.htm) seems like it would work well. Ditto with this [Ubuntu Rescue Remix CD](http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org). But if you hook up the drive itself to a real Linux setup.

**The longer answer?** I wrote this lengthy explanation on how to detect connected block level devices and mount them just in case you—or someone else—wants to go down this route. I feel it’s always nicer to know how the nuts and bolts basics of how a system works when dealing with stuff as potentially tricky as data recovery goes.

So I believe the basic Linux/Unix command you are looking for is to view all paritions on a device is [`lsblk`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsblk); list block devices. For example, this is the output of `lsblk` on an Ubuntu Linux virtual machine I use for development and testing:

```
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                             8:0    0    32G  0 disk 
├─sda1                          8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                          8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5                          8:5    0  31.8G  0 part 
  ├─sandbox--vg-root (dm-0)   252:0    0  27.8G  0 lvm  /
  └─sandbox--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0     4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

This might look confusing, but if you understand it is showing you a list of devices as well as partitions on them, you can more easily interpret what is happening. For example, looking at this output you can see that `sda5` has two distinct partitions on it: `sandbox--vg-root`/`dm-0` and `sandbox--vg-swap_1`/`dm-1`. Since `sandbox--vg-root`/`dm-0` is the larger of the two partitions, we can safely assume that is the main partition. And if I wanted to recover data from `sandbox--vg-root`/`dm-0`, I could mount that in Linux by running a mount command.

Now, let’s say that `lsblk` is not an installed tool on your live CD. Then no problem: Then just look directly at the list of available partitions by running this command:

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

And the example output from my  Ubuntu Linux test virtual machine is as follows:

```
  11        0    1048575 sr0
   8        0   33554432 sda
   8        1     248832 sda1
   8        2          1 sda2
   8        5   33302528 sda5
 252        0   29106176 dm-0
 252        1    4194304 dm-1
```

Now in this case, it’s not as clear that `dm-0` and `dm-1`, but it’s fair to assume they are partitions you are looking for by deducing that they directly follow `sda5` and the total size of `sda5` reflects the sum of `dm-0` and `dm-1`.

With that done, we now know that we would want to mount `sandbox--vg-root`/`dm-0`. And in the case of a writable Linux environment, you would do something like this. First, create a directory that the volume would be mounted to; this would create `~/recover_mount` in your home directory:

```
mkdir ~/recover_mount/
```

And then you would mount the device to `~/recover_mount/` like this:

```
sudo mount /dev/dm-0 ~/recover_mount/
```

With that done, if you ran `ls -la ~/recover_mount/`, you would be able to access all of the contents of the main partition on that drive with ease.

But this is all assuming you are mounting a Linux partition from another Linux machine. If you are on Linux but want to mount a Windows partition, it might get trickier. In a best case scenario, we can assume the Windows disk is NTFS so it an be mounted like so:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/dm-0 ~/recover_mount/
```

Note the `-t` setting of `ntfs`. Or perhaps you need to change that to `ntfs-3g` like this:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/dm-0 ~/recover_mount/
```

But most of all, your Linux live CD would need to have NTFS support. Most modern kernels do by default. But honestly if you are serious about data recovery in a case like this, it might be better to remove the drive from the Windows machine and hook it up to a working Linux system—not a live CD—and attempt to do what have outlined that way.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your well explained answer. Unfortunately, the Helix distro that I used (HelixR12009) didn't have the correct permissions to write to an external drive (I spent many hours trying to figure that out). So we actually just scraped this idea, created an bootable unbuntu USB, used the dd command to perform a block level copy onto an external harddisk, then plugged that same external harddisk onto a windows machine and download free data recovery software to use on that external drive. And that actually worked for us.

Comment: And I'm sorry I can't upvote this answer, I don't have a high enough rep.